# any way to interrupt Concurrent.Futures?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

Is there any way to interrupt concurrent.futures executor.map after a certain number of processes have completed their tasks?
My goal is to be able to interrupt executor.map, change the values of the items in the list it is taking from and then continue executor.map. is this possible?
If not is there a way to use executor.map with a single value one at a time instead of it taking values from a list?

Comment: I can't help you much without a code provided, but there is a method called `cancel` -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.cancel which attempts to cancel the current call

Comment: I think my issue is that executor.map goes through the entire list of iterables before the next line and i have no idea how to perform checks during map or cancel it mid way through before it completes